# display sum of individual items in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to display individual item name and its sum value. Could you please help me.

```
 const meals = [
    { calorie: 10,
      diet: 'Chicken',
      day: 1
    },
    { calorie: 15,
      diet: 'Soya',
      day: 2
    },
    { calorie: 20,
       diet: 'Chicken',
       day: 3
    },
    { calorie: 25,
        diet: 'Soya',
        day: 4
      }
  ];
```

my output :
sum of diet(chicken) is = 30 (10 + 20)
sum of diet(Soya) is = 40 (15 +25)
I want to display both Diet name and total calories like below.

```
Chicken = 30
  Soya = 40
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: yes worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the sum for each diet.

```js
const meals = [
    { calorie: 10,
      diet: 'Chicken',
      day: 1
    },
    { calorie: 15,
      diet: 'Soya',
      day: 2
    },
    { calorie: 20,
       diet: 'Chicken',
       day: 3
    },
    { calorie: 25,
        diet: 'Soya',
        day: 4
      }
  ];
const res = meals.reduce((acc,{calorie, diet})=>
     (acc[diet]=(acc[diet] || 0) + calorie, acc),{});
for(const key in res){
  console.log(key,'=',res[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const meals = [{
    calorie: 10,
    diet: 'Chicken',
    day: 1
  },
  {
    calorie: 15,
    diet: 'Soya',
    day: 2
  },
  {
    calorie: 20,
    diet: 'Chicken',
    day: 3
  },
  {
    calorie: 25,
    diet: 'Soya',
    day: 4
  }
];

const output = meals.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.diet]) acc[cur.diet] = 0;
  acc[cur.diet] += cur.calorie
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: instead of returning as object , is it possible to display like Chicken = 30 and Soya = 40

Comment: not sure your purpose, but you can just access output.Chicken and output.Soya

Answer (score 0):

The sum can be achieved using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const meals = [{calorie:10,diet:'Chicken',day:1},{calorie:15,diet:'Soya',day:2},{calorie:20,diet:'Chicken',day:3},{calorie:25,diet:'Soya',day:4}]

const calculateSum = (data) => data.reduce((res, {
  calorie,
  diet
}) => {
//Add/update the object with key as `diet` 
//sum up the calories with the previous value, 
//if the object is not present in the `res` object then add the calories to `0`
  res[diet] = (res[diet] || 0) + calorie;
  return res;
}, {})

console.log(calculateSum(meals));
```

Once the object is formed, then it can be displayed in the required format.